# Editing and Compiling the MPIs FORTRAN code

Tags: linux, fortran, mpi, parallel-processing

I have very basic question about the use of high performance cluster in our university and MPIs with FORTRAN. I have copied my FORTRAN code to the cluster to include the MPIs as I cannot compile my MPI Fortran code outside the cluster; on cluster I am using the emacs as editor.

This editing is very slow due to the emacs, especially to write something from start. Is there any way to edit, compile, link and execute the Fortran MPIs code outside the cluster? If everything starts working properly so at the end I can copy the code to cluster to run in parallel. This will make my life very easy. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Zahur Ullah

Comment: As in the answer by janneb, you just need to setup your MPI library on your local computer.  Alternatively, you could learn to use an editor like ViM or Emacs and do your coding on the cluster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you're asking whether it's possible to install a Fortran (not FORTRAN!) development environment including a MPI library on a machine which isn't a cluster?

Well, yes, of course it's possible to do that.

Comment: Yes, this is what i want to ask. The main reason is that it is very difficult to edit the code on editor available on cluster the emacs (dos type editor) and again it is not very easy to transfer the code from cluster for editing and copying back after editing for very small changes. 
So  how is it possible ?

Comment: @zahoorullah: Well you install and set up a Fortran compiler, debugger, editor, libraries you need (such as MPI), and then you develop your program. Then when your program is ready and works on your workstation, you copy the source to the cluster, recompile, and run.

Comment: @zahoorullah: And, emacs is a "dos type editor"? What is that supposed to mean?